# issue reverting jspm back to 0.16.53 (last stable build)

Tags: jspm

I recently tried latest beta version of jspm "0.17.0-beta.47" in a local version of a project that i pull from a git repository.
Didnt have much success so deleted the project and did a fresh git clone to set everything back.

so the project is backed to using jspm@0.16.53 and usually works fine but since trying this beta version and reverting back every time i run 'jspm install' it tries to add the following line to our config.js file

"systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"

where as before this didnt happen. its also crashing when i run the tests on my local machine with the error

' Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9877jspm_packages/npm/es6-iterator@2.0.3.json
        Error loading http://localhost:9877jspm_packages/npm/es6-iterator@2.0.3.json!http://localhost:9877jspm_packages/github/systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2.js as "../es6-iterator@2.0.3.json!systemjs-json" from http://localhost:9877jspm_packages/npm/es6-iterator@2.0.3/array.js'

like i say this didnt do this before i tried the beta version. i got a collegue to git clone the project onto his machine and everything works fine so its
acting as if trying out the beta version has left some global setting on my machine that i cant remove.

any suggestions what could be happening?

Comment: Did you tried to remove jspm_packages folder and run jspm install from scratch?

Comment: hi Pavel, yes. I basically deleted the whole project from my machine. pulled down from our git repository the version of the project that uses jspm@0.16.53. the jspm_packages folder and node_modules folders are not in source control so you have to run npm install and jspm install to get the projects dependencies.